# How do you Mask URLs in HAProxy?

Tags: url, load-balancing, haproxy, masking, url-masking

Is there any way to do URL masking in HAProxy? I'd like to have a URL directing to my load balancer, i.e. [www.example.com](http://example.com), redirect to another URL I have for another application. However, I'd like the user's browser to still display the original URL, ([www.example.com](http://example.com)). How would I go about this?

Comment: Seems that the answer has been given on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/699399/how-do-you-mask-urls-in-haproxy